# How to add media queries to styles prop in react-select?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I want to add a media query to make the width of the control object change on 768px width and beyond but I'm not able to add JavaScript to the control function under styles.

```
const mediaquery = "@media (min-width: 768px)"

<Select
  styles={{
    control: (base: CSSProperties, state: ControlProps<{}>) => ({
      ...base,
      width: "200px",
      // below code throws an error
      mediaquery: { width: "400px" }
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the react-select document, you could provide a className props to the element. Here is the reference: https://react-select.com/styles#using-classnames

You may create a .css file and define all the media queries there. And then import the .css file like `import './style.css';` in your react-select component.